# Matrix variate t-distribution and product of Beta distributions

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability, st.statistics, probability-distributions

This is a reference request for the following result. Let $X$ be a random matrix following the matrix variate $t$-distribution $T_{p,m}(\nu, M, U, V)$ (as defined in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_t-distribution)). Then
$$
\frac{\det(U)}{\det\bigl(U + (X-M)V^{-1}{(X-M)}'\bigr)}
$$ 
has the same distribution as the product $B_1 \ldots B_m$ of $m$ independent random variables $B_i \sim \textrm{Beta}\left(\frac{\nu+m-i}{2}, \frac{p}{2}\right)$.

This result is checked by simulations in R below.

This result is given in Geisser's article [Bayesian estimation in multivariate analysis](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.aoms/1177700279) but it is a bit hidden: it is given in a Bayesian context where a particular matrix variate $t$-distribution appears without name, and the proof is only sketched.

I'm looking for a reference which precisely states this result. It is not given in Gupta & Nagar's book *Matrix variate distributions*.

```
library(LaplacesDemon) # to simulate Wishart distribution

# simulates matrix normal N_{p,m}(M, U ⊗ V)
rmatrixnormal <- function(M, U, V){
  Z <- matrix(rnorm(nrow(M)*ncol(M)), nrow(M), ncol(M))
  M + t(chol(U)) %*% Z %*% chol(V)
}

# parameters of the matrix t-distribution
p <- 5; m <- 3
U <- rwishart(p, diag(p)) # arbitray U matrix
V <- rwishart(m, diag(m)) # arbitrary V matrix
Vinv <- solve(V) # inverse V
nu <- 6 # degrees of freedom

# simulations of matrix t-distribution
nsims <- 25000
sims <- numeric(nsims)
for(i in 1:nsims){
  Psi <- rinvwishart(nu+m-1, V)
  X <- rmatrixnormal(matrix(0,p,m), U, Psi)
  sims[i] <- det(U)/det(U + X %*% Vinv %*% t(X))
}

# simulations of product of m Beta distributions
k <- (nu+m-1)/2
sims2 <- rbeta(nsims, k, p/2)*rbeta(nsims, k-0.5, p/2)*rbeta(nsims, k-1, p/2)

# compare cumulative distribution functions
curve(ecdf(sims)(x), from=0, to=1)
curve(ecdf(sims2)(x), col="red", add=TRUE, lty=2, lwd=3)
```

[image]